Tensorflow Conv1d kernel size for time series
I am really new at this topic, so please bear with me. I have the following problem:
I'm trying to use a CNN model to predict sleep stages with an ecg signal and some other features. The ecg singal is sampled in 265 hz and the data is split into 30 second epochs, so I have 7680 datapoints per 30s epoch. I want to run these epochs through a cnn so the shape for the first Conv1D Layer should be (None, 7680, 1) -> (BatchSize, TimeSteps, data) if I got the documentation right. Now I want to have a 5x1 window for the first layer, so I set the kernel_size=5. But then I get the following error:

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for '{{node
functional_1/conv1d_1/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT,
data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[],
padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](functional_1/conv1d_1/convolution/ExpandDims,
functional_1/conv1d_1/convolution/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes:
[?,1,1,1], [1,5,1,32].

tf version: 2.17.0
So my goal is to have a window of 5x1 for the layer, how do I do that or rather how do I to shape the data to make this work? (This example shows what I need -> Example with kernel size 3)
My model:
    ecg_input = Input(shape=(7680, 1), name='ecg')
    activity_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='activity_normalized')
    time_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='relative_time')
    position_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='relative_position')
    
    conv1 = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=5 , activation='relu')(ecg_input)
    conv1 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(conv1)
    conv2 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv1D(128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(conv2)
    conv3 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv3)

    conv_flat = Flatten()(conv3)

    x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([conv_flat, activity_input, time_input, position_input])
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

    output = x

I tried reshaping the data to (1, 7680) as it seems to be in the torch example linked above, but this did not work for tensorflow / keras.
So if you have an idea why this error accures and how to fix it or what to improve on the structure itself, please let me know! Any feedback is highly appreciated!

